# Use arrays as data sources in timeseries chart C3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I want to use arrays as sources in the C3.js chart like this:

```
var xData = ['2017-07-28', '2017-07-29'];
var yData = [30, 200];

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
        columns: [
            ['x', xData],
            ['data1', yData]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But it gives me errors like:

> Failed to parse x '2017-07-28,2017-07-29' to Date object
>
> Error:  attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN, 0)".

If I use direct values then it works perfectly:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2017-07-28', '2017-07-29'],
            ['data1', 30, 200]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,

```
['x', xData]
```

is equal to

```
['x', ['2017-07-28', '2017-07-29']]
```

not

```
['x', '2017-07-28', '2017-07-29']
```

What you can do is create the array before :

```
var xData = ['2017-07-28', '2017-07-29'];
var yData = [30, 200];

xData.unshift('x');
yData.unshift('data1');

var chart = c3.generate({
     bindto: '#chart',
     data: {
         x: 'x',
         xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
         columns: [
             xData,
             yData
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
             type: 'timeseries',
             tick: {
                 format: '%Y-%m-%d'
             }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I also figure out that later. Thanks anyway!